# G752 Asus Gaming laptop

Tags: 14.04, 15.10

Is there a version of ubuntu this is working on?  I have tried fedora, centos, ubuntu and can not seem to get any of these working with a new install.  I can understand having troubles but I can't even get the installs to complete so I can troubleshoot and fix minor problems here and there.  I am using a bootable USB by the way and have tried many different versions of all the above and even tried cd's.  No luck on any installations.  I despise windows and have already wiped the windows clean off it.

Comment: Please speify the problem in which step do the problem occur

Comment: Mohit,  The problem starts with the install.  When ever I try to just run it on the usb since it's bootable it won't even run on the USB also it won't install.  I don't see where it errors out.  I mean it has an error for the sound card but that shouldn't stop the install process.  The install never completes and just sits there.  It goes to a black screen so I don't see any errors or failures.

Comment: Did u disable Fast Startup on Windows https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?54342-Dual-booting-Windows-8-1-amp-Ubuntu-14-04-in-G751JT. You system should support any linux distro's.

Comment: Yes I had to so I could enable CSM and PXE boot.

Comment: Dose all the OS's show a black screen for is it different for each OS u tried???

Comment: some OS goes thru the install things scroll across the screen and it fails but I don't see where... I should be installing the ubuntu amd version 64 bit for this right?

Comment: Yes you can install 64bit

Answer (score 0):

You may have not created your USB correctly if it  won't run ... Or you have not configured your BIOS to change the boot order on USB.

You can find how to create a bootable USB stick of Ubuntu on Windows:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

I checked for issues with your computer's model... The only problem which come back is for the  detection of the SSD :  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2307273

Comment: It boots off the USB because it comes into where I can install or boot USB device.  I have it configured properly in the bios and created the USB right or it wouldn't do that.  I used the instructions above to do it.  I am looking for a version of linux that will install on this hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 on Asus G752VM.

I used a USB stick with 16.04.1.
Touchpad and Fn keys don't work - everything else works fine and mostly out of the box.

I disabled SecureBoot and Fastboot in the BIOS and switched to CSM (instead of EFI). Not sure if disabling Fastboot was even necessary.

Nouveau doesn't really support the Nvidia 1060 yet - after booting the live system you only get 800x600 resolution. But it's good enough to get to "Software & Updates" -> "Additional Drivers" (after activating the other channels under "Ubuntu Software") and activate the official nvidia driver.